# oAuth2 REST Client in Spring Boot 2.0 M6 (Spring Security 5.0)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I´m trying to upgrade from Spring Boot 2.0 M3 to the current M6 milestone. In Milestone M5 they changed the oAuth2 Client behavior in Spring Security 5.

Now I´m confused how to reconfigure my application to fit the changed oAuth2 implementation using Microsoft Botframework oAuth2 REST API. I´m using the dependency: `org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client` in the current version 5.0 RC1.

My current guess is this:

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          botframework:
            client-id: myClientId
            client-secret: myClientSecret
            scope: https://api.botframework.com/.default
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-authentication-method: form
        provider:
          botframework:
            token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Configuration to allow oAuth2 Login**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
}
```

Now I need to get the access token to fire a request against the Botframework REST API. Before the version upgrade this was done by using the oAuth2 REST Template. Do I still need this and if yes, how?

Currently the Spring Boot 2.0 M6 auto configuration doesn´t work for me. Any ideas on this topic?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @RegisteredUser Yes, see my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is now:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: ************
      client-secret: *************
      access-token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
      scope: https://api.botframework.com/.default
      grant-type: client_credentials
      client-authentication-scheme: form
```

and

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security.oauth2.client")
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oauth2RemoteResource() {
    return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
}
```

and everything is allowed for now

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the bean for? and where to put it?